# How to Build Homestead (Vagrant) Box using Packer?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, packer

I have followed the instruction in laravel/setter [markdown](https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/readme.md).

I have already:

1. Clone `chef/bento` into same top level folder as this repo.
2. Run `./bin/copy-to-bento.sh`
3. Replace `scripts/cleanup.sh` with `scripts/homestead.sh` in file `ubuntu/ubuntu-18.04-amd64.json`

But when it comes to step 4, I had no idea how to begin. The packer [documentation](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/vagrant.html) seems too advanced for me to read. I just installed packer via `sudo apt-get install packer` command in my Ubuntu. Then how to proceed the last step?

I want to build homestead box because of extreme slow speed of adding vagrant box using `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` command. If anyone have other idea and alternative to add/install this box, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just run:

```
packer build -only virtualbox-iso ubuntu/ubuntu-18.04-amd64.json
```

(Assuming you also have VirtualBox installed)

Comment: where we assume this command to be executed? is it same as bento & settler directory level?

Comment: At the root of the bento repository, wherever that is for you.

Comment: the command works only in bento/ubuntu directory, and modified to 'packer build -only virtualbox-iso ubuntu-18.04-amd64.json'